# getting this PyQt6 error "This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized on M1 silicon Mac in PyCharm "

Tags: python, pyqt6, apple-silicon

I am trying to run an application on my M1 silicon Mac on my PyCharm project and I keep getting the same problem after it runs correcly for the first time.

I have tried most suggestions from different but running into the same errors

> qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "cocoa" in ""
> This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Some things I have done include

1. Setting the QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH Environment Variable:
2. Reinstalling pyqt6
3. Creating a new virtual environment

etc